# startActivity from background service leads to strange task-switching behaviour

Tags: android, android-activity, background

My app consists mainly of two activities, A and B, and a background service (started by alarms).
Activity A is the launcher (main) activity. 
Activity B is started every now and then by the background service, with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK set (this is required for activity starts in bg services).

**Desired behaviour**: Whenever the app is left (return to homescreen, backbutton etc.) and the user returns to it, Activity A shall be resumed.

**My problem**: Whenever B has been started by the background service, the app will **always** return to B through the activity switcher (home-button long press), no matter if I have closed it via back-button or not. I can then only return to Activity A if I select the home icon of the app (because A is then started as launch activity).

I think this has to do with fact that B is started in a new task by the background service, and the app-switcher tries to return to this new task. But shouldn't the new task end when I close B via back-button, returning to A?

Can someone please explain to me what's the matter here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full and final solution is to add the below code to the activity in the menifest file which is opened by the service.

```
android:taskAffinity="" 
android:excludeFromRecents="true" 
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: is it so that without blanking out the taskAffinity, the new task (FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) has overwritten the old one?

Comment: There is no need for android:taskAffinity="" attribute in the menifest file

Comment: Yes there is, I actually had the other two attributes already set.